# What is the easiest way to hint localizations while typing?

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview, google-geocoder

I think I could use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` to show hints. But how can I get some hints from Geocode API while typing it (e.g. where there are at least 3 letters typed)

Any idea?

Comment: Do you need autocomplete for places?

Comment: @xomena yes, yes. After typing minimum 3 characters in input text, the application shows location hints (containing city and country), after clicking on the hint, the application sets it as user location - I need something like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can use Places API for Android.

Please look at this web site:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Places API for Android provides Place autocomplete and Place picker.